# Html CSS Some padding and margin

Tags: html, css

Can anybody tell me why class "Login2" is going out of the  parent  "login" 
I'm using

```css
#login2 {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:#e8eceb;
}
```

## [Full code demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sr7kr3gz/12/)

Comment: The reason is because your getting 100% of the parents height but have the text before it... so its being pushed down.

Comment: youv'e used relative sizing, and it's relative to the parent. so `#login2` is taking 100% of `#login1`'s size, which DOESN"T take into account that you've got that "Login to admin panel" taking up space.

Comment: Why not just put the title in its own div? [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sr7kr3gz/18/). I don't see the point of having login2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can anybody tell me why class "Login2" is going out of the parent "login"

### The Problem

Both your `#login` and `#login2` elements have a computed height of 300px. What you're doing here is neglecting to include the "Login to Admin Panel" text which exists alongside your `#login2` element within the `#login` element.

This text itself has a computed height of 23px (in Chrome). This means already the `#login2` element is pushed down by 23px. On top of that, our `#login2` element also has a `margin-top` property set to 5px, meaning in total our `#login2` element is pushed down by 28px. Because of this, the distance from the top of `#login` to the bottom of `#login2` is 328px - *not* the 300px we're looking for.

### A Solution

An easy way to fix this is to simply wrap your "Login to Admin Panel" text in its own element which has its own fixed height defined; then account for both that element's height *and* the `margin-top` in our `#login2` element's height:

```css
body{
    background-color: #bdd7d1;
}

#container {
    width: 320px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #d0e1dd;
    border: 1px solid white;
    padding:10px;
    margin-left:auto;
   margin-right:auto;
}
#login  {

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: #404040;
    border: 1px solid #404040;
    color: white;
}
#login2 {
    margin-top:5px;
    width:100%;
    height:270px;
    background-color:#e8eceb;
}

#login p {
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="login">
    <p>Login to Admin Panel</p>
    <div id="login2">
      <div id="buttonPlace">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I've done in this code snippet is wrap your "Login to Admin Panel" text within `<p>` tags, and styled that to set its `height` and `line-height` to 25px, and remove any margins on it which the browser may add itself. I've then done a bit of maths to work out what height the `#login2` element needs to be to make it fit perfectly:

```
h = Height of #login element
m = Top margin of #login2 element
p = Height of newly-added p element
d = Required height

h - m - p = d

300px - 25px - 5px = 270px
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change:

```
height:100%;
```

to:

```
height:auto;
```

Jsfiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sr7kr3gz/13/

Comment: So this is the only option?I want fill whole login2

Comment: I don't think it is there are many ways to fix this but this is the easiest fix with your code.

Comment: @Stefan There are a few ways to fix this.

Comment: @ArturK. What do you exactly mean with "fill" whole login2?

Comment: If I use height:auto; I need to fill the div with some stuff to see the color of the div

Answer (score 0):

It's caused by two things:

- First the `margin-top` value and second the size of the Text **Login to Admin Panel**

What you can do is assign a wrapper to the title and set a fixed height:

```
<div class="title">Login to Admin Panel</div>

#login .title {
    height:20px;
    line-height:20px;
}
```

Then use `calc` to set the right `height` of the panel:

```
#login2 {
    width:100%;
    height:calc(100% - 20px);
    background-color:#e8eceb;
}
```

#### [UpdatedFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sr7kr3gz/17/)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `overflow: hidden` on the parent `#login`.  Something like this maybe what you want:

```css
body {
  background-color: #bdd7d1;
}
#container {
  width: 320px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #d0e1dd;
  border: 1px solid white;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
#login {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: #404040;
  border: 1px solid #404040;
  color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#login2 {
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #e8eceb;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="login">Login to Admin Panel
      <div id="login2">
        <div id="buttonPlace"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest reducing your number of elements by making use of the `:before` and/or `:after` css pseudo elements, ***removing the need for the #login2 element altogether***.

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/sr7kr3gz/21/)

In order to make the form aesthetically pleasing, i've removed your #login2 and replaced it with a pseudo element :after.

```css
body {
    background-color: #bdd7d1;
}
#container {
    width: 320px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #d0e1dd;
    border: 1px solid white;
    padding:10px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
#login {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position:relative;
    text-align: center;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: #404040;
    border: 1px solid #404040;
    color: white;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#login:after {
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:5px;
    width:100%;
    height: calc(100%);
    background-color:#e8eceb;
    left:0;
    top:22px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="login">Login to Admin Panel
        <div id="buttonPlace"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

To 'hide' the overflow, you can use the `overflow:hidden` property on the parent class.

---

The reason behind this effect is this:

you have set the size of the two 'login's' as 100%, like so:

```
+-------+        +-------+
|       |        |       |
|       |        |       |
|       |        |       |
|       |        |       |
+-------+        +-------+
```

so they'll be the same height (initially).

However, when you place text in one, you'll get this:

```
+-------+        
|TEXT   |        
|       |        
|       |        
|       |               
+-------+ 
+-------+  <-- inner container set as 100%; so in effect it has been 'pushed down'
```

And so in order to do this, you need to ensure your child element is actually the size you need it to be, minus the height of the text.

---

## Alternative

---

An alternative to using overflow:hidden would be to use a calculation for the height, and so will end up with something like this:

```
#login:after {
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:5px;
    width:100%;
    height: calc(100% - 27px); /*computed height of 'white area' required*/
    background-color:#e8eceb;
    left:0;
    top:22px; /*Height of text*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your case i would color only the headline itself and let the #login2 auto-scale in height, due it is relative to the parent DIV #login:

**HTML**:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="login">
    <span class="hl">Login to Admin Panel</span>
    <div id="login2">
      <div id="buttonPlace"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#login  {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: #e8eceb;
    border: 1px solid #404040;
    color: white;
}
#login2 {
    margin-top:5px;
}
#container .hl {
    display: block;
    background: #404040;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sr7kr3gz/19/